# Why this React CRUD goes back to initial state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm practicing react and I'm working on a simple crud. The problem I'm facing is that when I insert a new element, my app is going back to the initial state. I'm not sure how to fix this. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Tabela from "./Tabela";

import Form from "./Formulario";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    autores: [
      {
        nome: "Paulo",
        livro: "React",
        preco: "1000",
      },
      {
        nome: "Daniel",
        livro: "Java",
        preco: "99",
      },
      {
        nome: "Marcos",
        livro: "Design",
        preco: "150",
      },
      {
        nome: "Bruno",
        livro: "DevOps",
        preco: "100",
      },
    ],
  };

  removeAutor = (index) => {
    const { autores } = this.state;

this.setState({
  autores: autores.filter((autor, posAtual) => {
    return posAtual !== index;
  }),
});
  };

  escutadorDeSubmit = autor => {
    this.setState({ autores: [...this.state.autores, autor]})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Tabela autores={this.state.autores} removeAutor={this.removeAutor} />
        <Form escutadorDeSubmit = {this.escutadorDeSubmit} />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and this is the other class Formulario.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Formulario extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.stateInicial = {
        nome:'',
        livro:'',
        preco:''
    }

    this.state = this.stateInicial;
}

escutadorDeInput = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    this.setState({
        [name] : value
    });
}

submitFormulario = () => {
    this.props.escutadorDeSubmit(this.state);
    this.setState(this.stateInicial);
}

render() {

    const { nome, livro, preco } = this.state;

    return (
        <form>

            <label htmlFor="nome">Nome</label>
            <input
                id="nome"
                type="text"
                name="nome"
                value={nome} 
                onChange= {this.escutadorDeInput} />
            <label htmlFor="livro">Livro</label>
            <input
                id="livro"
                type="text"
                name="livro"
                value={livro} 
                onChange= {this.escutadorDeInput} />
            <label htmlFor="preco">Preco</label>
            <input
                id="preco"
                type="text"
                name="preco"
                value={preco} 
                onChange= {this.escutadorDeInput} />
            <button onClick={this.submitFormulario}>Salvar</button>
        </form>
    );
}
}
export default Formulario;
```

When I insert the new author, the app shows the new input for a second and then reloads to the initial state. I'd like to keep the record that I just inserted and not lose it.

Comment: Hi, can you provide Tabela component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your submit function for the form. As the button is in the form, it gets implicitly the `type="submit"` attribute. This means, when you click on it, the form tries to submit it's values to some url, as it its default behaviour. You can prevent this, by using `preventDefault()` in your submit function:

```
submitFormulario = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.escutadorDeSubmit(this.state);
    this.setState(this.stateInicial);
}
```

An alternative would be to take the button out of the form or give it explicitly the `type="button"` attribute.